# How do you get started on game dev in js on Win8?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Can someone point me at some helpful docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a lot of room for answer depending on what kind of game you're talking about, but here's some stuff to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452744

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452754

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465158

And a code sample.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/JavaScript-and-HTML5-touch-d96f6031